# Java, getting rid of unchecked conversion for method returning an object

Tags: java, generics, casting

I've yet another case of unchecked warning that I cannot get rid of. Code looks like this:

```java
public <FV, V> V getFieldValue ( String fieldName, Function<FV, V> converter )
{
  FV fieldValue = (FV) getFieldValue ( fieldName ); // this returns an object
  return converter.apply ( fieldValue )
}
```

This code compiles and works fine, but Eclipse (and Java compiler) complaints that the FV casting is unsafe. Yes, it is, yet I'd like to rely on the caller knowing what they are doing, so I'd like to remove the warning.

Eclipse proposes me to add `@SuppressWarnings ( "unchecked" )` at either the assignment or the method level, neither changes a thing. Is it possible to tell the compiler I'm fine with it and I don't want to be bothered?

If you are thinking that `getFieldValue()` should use a generic and not an Object, yes, I know, but it's very ancient code that I can't change.

Comment: `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` would remove the warning. Maybe you need to clean/rebuild

Comment: @ernest_k, no, I usually try to pay attention to such things, I rebuilt it many times, still the same warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only actually safe way to deal with this is to remove the reason you need FV at all: pass a `Function<Object, V>` (or `Function<Object, ? extends V>`) instead.

Comment: Thanks! That works. The caller is forced to use typecasting in lamda expressions, besides it was so with the AT generic too.

Answer (score 0):

This should work as expected `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`. If this doesn't work, you can try `@SuppressWarnings("all")`

Comment: Uhm... thanks, but I don't want to force the caller to send in the class.

Comment: From the Javadoc, it looks to be compiler dependent. Maybe @SuppressWarnings("all") can work as your method is short this is safe to suppress all. Sure not great to add a parameter :) I updated my answer then

Comment: Tries "all", still the same, sadly.